# Some Virus is creating "Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SqlManagement" folder again and again

Tags: virus, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server, virus-removal, trojan

c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SqlManagement folder is creating again and again in our Windows server 2008 R2. SqlManagement folder contains some files with SystemManagement.exe and SqlManagement.exe.

[screenshot of folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gQZO.jpg)

Looks like it is a virus. We have tried multiple antivirus but it is only able to delete the folder but It’s not detecting the program that’s re-creating.
Malwarebytes antivirus is showing this virus as Trojan.BitCoinMiner
Please guide me to remove this virus.

Comment: Can you verify that you are NOT running MS SQL Server or the SQL Management programs? Can you right-click on the EXEs, choose Properties, and view the Details tab to see who created it?